# Новая вкладка в window.opener

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: 
мне нужно открыть ссылку в новой вкладке, относительно родительского окна.

Подробнее:
Есть **Окно1**, в нем есть ссылка, при клике на которую (через window.open(...) ) открывается попап - **Окно2**
В **Окне2**, тоже есть ссылка - **Ссылка2**.
Так вот, при клике на **Ссылку2** два мне нужно открыть новое окно рядом с **Окном1**.
Все что получается сделать это:

```
window.opener.location = '**Ссылка2**.href';
```

Но это откроет в самом **Окне1**, а не в новой вкладке.

Comment: Зря вы вернули метку *jquery*, он тут никаким боком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь это сделать на двух разных доменах, то политика безопасности категорически запрещает такое. Обойти можно только одном случае, если iframe находится на субдомене (sub.domain.com) и тогда можно будет приравнять `document.domain = "domain.com"` этому домену, что позволит выполнить `window.parent.open`.

Comment: Да, делаю на разных доменах. Я так и думал, что это сделать нельзя, но хотел уточнить у более опытных людей.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Не большой знаток js-а, но можно, например, решить это так.

**1.html** aka **Окно1**. Объявляем функцию, открывающую новую вкладку с нужным урлом.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    spawnTab = function(url) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('2.html', '_blank', 'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,status=no,width=200,height=200');">open popup</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**2.html** aka **Окно2**. Пинаем вышеупомянутую функцию.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="window.opener.spawnTab('http://google.com');">open tab in parent</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не завелось, но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы локально пробовали ил на сервере? Локально не заведется из соображений безопасности браузера: он не даст постороннему фрейму (2) приказать другому фрейму (1) открыть еще один фрейм, если url фреймов 2 и 1 не имеет одинаковый протокол, имя хоста и порт. При открытии файлов просто с диска это условие считается невыполненным.

Comment: Нет, я пробовал не локально. Но браузер всеравно не дает обратится к window.opener.spawnTab();